# SammyJS does not always fire route

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js

I am currently developing on a small SPA using sammyjs + knockoutjs.

I have an index.html that contains the routing mechanism and a div with id 'main'.

In my sample that I reduced to the issue there is a page 1 and page 2 that loads an html page using partial. The particular html page has knockout bindings.

The problem: When I switch between the pages using a link the routing does not always fire. When reloading the page with the appropriate link it fires and loads without problems.

I tried to put it into a JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/ufOroze/3/edit?html,js,console,output

When you click on the links they should actually load some content from a remote html file (p1.html and p2.html) -- although this does not work with JSBin. Anyway. You see the call, that is not always fired, and the link on the console.

I also put an example on my server under . There you also find a link to the zip-file containing the whole example: http://www.tomgrill.info/sammy_test/sammy_test.zip.

Anybody an idea? Do I misunderstand the concept of sammyjs oder is there a bug?

best, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not harvest the power of knockout and let it render the #main div for you, now you mix knockout and jQuery.

I've made a light weight SPA bootstrapper for KO, here is a demo project

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo

It takes handles the templates for you in convention over configuration way.

**edit:** Wiki that shows how to set it up on any backend

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap/wiki

Basically you need to expose a REST service that returns the templates

Comment: Hi. I had a look at your code. Great approach. Do you also have a pure HTML/Javascript/Knockout Version of it. Would be really helpful (as I am not on Windows and not using Visual Studio). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :-

```
app = $.sammy('body', function (context) {
    this.get('#/', function () {
        console.log('Clicked');
        this.app.swap('sammy test');
    });
    this.get('#/:id', function () {
        console.log('Clicked');
        var id = this.params.id;
        ko.unapplyBindings($('#main'), false);
        this.partial('pages/' + id + '.html');
    });


});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I only want to change the content of the div (#main).

Comment: Figured out how it works. The approach is correct. Only had to reset the variables set within the particular pages to be loaded in order to be able reestablishing the ko bindings. It is not nice as the data has to be reinitialized every time when swapping the pages. But it works. :) Thank you!